# android put the data(s) from an activity to a table in another activity

Tags: android

I am developing an app, I'm still new with eclipse and android.I am making an app about PMT function from excel. Now i am only able to display the results like

```
First Payment :             Monthly Payment  
"some calculated result"    "some calculated result"
```

now, i am using an alert message or toast text to display it. I want it to be displayed on a table on a new activity, but i have no idea how to implement it.

This is my code for calculating the payments and displaying it(using a button):

```
public void mulaihitung(View v){
                    double New1 = 1.1, New2 = 1.2, New3 = 1.3, New4 = 1.4, New5 = 1.5;
                    double Used1 = 1.6, Used2 = 1.7, Used3 = 1.8, Used4 = 1.9, Used5 = 2.0;
                    double tenor1 = 12,tenor2 =24,tenor3=36,tenor4=48,tenor5=60;
                    double TLO1Z1=2.1,TLO2Z1=2.2,TLO3Z1=2.3,TLO4Z1=2.4,TLO5Z1=2.5;
                    double TLO1Z2=2.6,TLO2Z2=2.7,TLO3Z2=2.8,TLO4Z2=2.9,TLO5Z2=3.0;
                    double TLO1Z3=3.1,TLO2Z3=3.2,TLO3Z3=3.3,TLO4Z3=3.4,TLO5Z3=3.5;
                    double Combine1Z1 = 3.6,Combine2Z1 = 3.7,Combine3Z1 = 3.8,Combine4Z1 = 3.9,Combine5Z1 = 4.0;
                    double Combine1Z2 = 4.1,Combine2Z2 = 4.2,Combine3Z2 = 4.3,Combine4Z2 = 4.4,Combine5Z2 = 4.5;
                    double Combine1Z3 = 4.6,Combine2Z3 = 4.7,Combine3Z3 = 4.8,Combine4Z3 = 4.9,Combine5Z3 = 5.0;
                    double comphrehensive1Z1 = 5.1,comphrehensive2Z1 = 5.2,comphrehensive3Z1 = 5.3,comphrehensive4Z1 = 5.4,comphrehensive5Z1 = 5.5;
                    double comphrehensive1Z2 = 5.6,comphrehensive2Z2 = 5.7,comphrehensive3Z2 = 5.8,comphrehensive4Z2 = 5.9,comphrehensive5Z2 = 6.0;
                    double comphrehensive1Z3 = 6.1,comphrehensive2Z3 = 6.2,comphrehensive3Z3 = 6.3,comphrehensive4Z3 = 6.4,comphrehensive5Z3 = 6.5;
                    int firstinstallmentbelakang = 0,firstinstallmentdepan = 1;
                    double EffectiveRate = 0.01;
                    double fv = 0;
                    String ethint2 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                    String etpersen3 =etpersen2.getText().toString();
                    String textvDP2 =textvDP1.getText().toString();


                        if(ethint2.trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Silakan mengisi Harga Kendaraan terlebih dahulu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(etpersen3.trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Silakan mengisi persentase Uang muka/DP terlebih dahulu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;

                        }
                        else if(item1.toString().equals("-Pilih Kondisi-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Silakan memilih kondisi kendaraan terlebih dahulu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(item2.toString().equals("-Pilih Asuransi-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Silakan memilih jenis asuransi terlebih dahulu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(item3.toString().equals("-Pilih Zona Wilayah-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Silakan memilih zona wilayah terlebih dahulu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else{
                           if(ethint2.length()!=0 && etpersen3.length() !=0 && textvDP2.length() !=0){
                               String text1 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                                String text2 = etpersen2.getText().toString();
                                String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");    
                                if(text1.length()>0)
                                      input1 = Long.valueOf(text1);
                                if(text2.length()>0)
                                      input2 = Long.valueOf(text2);                
                                if (text1.length() != 0)      
                                     output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                                if(item1.toString().equals("New")&& item2.toString().equals("Combine")&& item3.toString().equals("Zona1")){
                                     output1 = input1 - output;
                                     pmt1 = (-(-EffectiveRate*(output1*Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor1)+fv)/((1+EffectiveRate*firstinstallmentdepan)*(Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor1)-1))));
                                     tumbal1 = (long) pmt1;
                                     pmt2 = (-(-EffectiveRate*(output1*Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor2)+fv)/((1+EffectiveRate*firstinstallmentdepan)*(Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor2)-1))));
                                     tumbal2 = (long) pmt2;
                                     pmt3 = (-(-EffectiveRate*(output1*Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor3)+fv)/((1+EffectiveRate*firstinstallmentdepan)*(Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor3)-1))));
                                     tumbal3 = (long) pmt3;
                                     pmt4 = (-(-EffectiveRate*(output1*Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor4)+fv)/((1+EffectiveRate*firstinstallmentdepan)*(Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor4)-1))));
                                     tumbal4 = (long) pmt4;
                                     pmt5 = (-(-EffectiveRate*(output1*Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor5)+fv)/((1+EffectiveRate*firstinstallmentdepan)*(Math.pow(1+EffectiveRate,tenor5)-1))));
                                     tumbal5 = (long) pmt5;
                                     hasilasuransi1 = output * (New1/100);
                                     tumbala1 = output + tumbal1 + hasilasuransi1;
                                     tumbalaa1 = (long)tumbala1;
                                     hasilasuransi2 = output * (New2/100);
                                     tumbala2 = output + tumbal2 + hasilasuransi2;
                                     tumbalaa2 = (long)tumbala2;
                                     hasilasuransi3 = output * (New3/100);
                                     tumbala3 = output + tumbal3 + hasilasuransi3;
                                     tumbalaa3 = (long)tumbala3;
                                     hasilasuransi4 = output * (New1/100);
                                     tumbala4 = output + tumbal4 + hasilasuransi4;
                                     tumbalaa4 = (long)tumbala4;
                                     hasilasuransi5 = output * (New5/100);
                                     tumbala5 = output + tumbal5 + hasilasuransi5;
                                     tumbalaa5 = (long)tumbala5;
                                  /*   Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbala1 +" Cicilan 1 tahun : " + tumbal1 + " IDR" + newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : "
                                     + tumbala2 + " Cicilan 2 tahun : "+tumbal2 +" IDR"+ newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbala3 + " Cicilan 3 tahun : "+ tumbal3 +" IDR"+ newline + 
                                     "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbala4 + " Cicilan 4 tahun : "+ tumbal4 +" IDR"+ newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbala5 + " Cicilan 5 tahun : "+
                                     tumbal5 +" IDR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/


                                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                        .setTitle("hasil")
                                        .setMessage("Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa1 + " IDR" +newline +" Cicilan 1 tahun : " + tumbal1 + " IDR" + newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : "
                                                 + tumbalaa2 + " IDR"  +newline + " Cicilan 2 tahun : "+tumbal2 +" IDR"+ newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa3 + " IDR"  + newline +" Cicilan 3 tahun : "+ tumbal3 +" IDR"+ newline + 
                                                 "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa4 + " IDR" +newline + " Cicilan 4 tahun : "+ tumbal4 +" IDR"+ newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa5 + " IDR"  +newline + " Cicilan 5 tahun : "+
                                                 tumbal5 +" IDR")
                                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            finish();    
                                        }

                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                                    .show();}
                                 }                                   
                              }
                           }
```

some explanation:
tumbal1,tumbal2,tumbal3.....and so on //for converting double result to long
tumbala1,tumbala2,tumbala3....and so on // calculating 1st payment
tumbalaa1,tumabalaa2,tumbalaa3.....and so on //for converting double to long
i am using long because the input could be more than 12 digits

public void mulaihitung = public void startcalculating(english translated)
mulaihitung is an OnClick on layout.xml ,example `<button  android:OnClick="mulaihitung"/> ,`
ethint is an edittext to input the price,
etpersen is an edittext to input the percentage of the price.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

is the alert dialog with option yes and no and all the result will be displayed there.

The results that will be displayed on alertdialog are from this lines

```
.setMessage("Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa1 + " IDR" +newline +" Cicilan 1 tahun : " + tumbal1 + " IDR" + newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : "
                                                     + tumbalaa2 + " IDR"  +newline + " Cicilan 2 tahun : "+tumbal2 +" IDR"+ newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa3 + " IDR"  + newline +" Cicilan 3 tahun : "+ tumbal3 +" IDR"+ newline + 
                                                     "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa4 + " IDR" +newline + " Cicilan 4 tahun : "+ tumbal4 +" IDR"+ newline + "Total Pembayaran Pertama : " + tumbalaa5 + " IDR"  +newline + " Cicilan 5 tahun : "+ tumbal5 +" IDR");
```

when we hit/click the button the alertdialog appear and it would look like this:(example)

```
Total Pembayaran Pertama 1000000 IDR
Cicilan 1 tahun 10000 IDR
Total Pembayaran Pertama 900000 IDR
Cicilan 2 tahun 9000 IDR
Total Pembayaran Pertama 800000 IDR
Cicilan 3 tahun 8000 IDR
Total Pembayaran Pertama 700000 IDR
Cicilan 4 tahun 7000 IDR
Total Pembayaran Pertama 600000 IDR
Cicilan 5 tahun 6000 IDR
```

Total Pembayaran Pertama = First Payment(English Translated), this comes from tumbalaa# calculation.
Cicilan # tahun = Monthly Payment for # year(s)(English Translated), this comes from tumbal# calculation

Comment: `I want it to be displayed on a table on a new activity` which data or when want to open new activity?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention it , a sec i ll update.thank you for reminding me

Comment: Edit: i am going home , will be not able to reply so fast. And no internet connection at home.Sorry in advance

Comment: the data from Total Pembayaran Pertama and Cicilan # Tahun, if u ask when, it will be displayed after we hit kalkulasi button that will validate the data first(all input filled and selected by the user) and then calculate the results